# Unable to run Custom OS ISO in Vmware Workstation Virtual Machine

Tags: operating-system, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I am trying to run a custom ISO in VMWare workstation.

You can refer my Github project for the source code.

When I run `mykernel.iso` base OS I am getting the following screen, instead of `printf()` that I have defined.

[image]